# In Keras, what is the difference between validation_set in fit_generator() and evaluate_generator()

Tags: keras, deep-learning

In Keras, it provides `fit_generator()` which contains parameter `validation_data`, and after each `validation_freq` we can see the `acc` and `val_acc` values. Another method `evaluate_generator()` also takes validation data and gives an accuracy score.

So my questions are:

1. what do `acc` and `val_acc` mean in `fit_generator()`, and why they differ?
2. Does validation_data refer to the same purpose as `evaluate_generator()`?

Comment: In question 1, do you mean `fit_generator()`? That's what I assumed in my answer, let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`acc` is accuracy on the training set. `val_acc` is accuracy on the validation set. `evaluate_generator()` will return a list of the results of all metrics, including the implied loss metric. Assuming that you compiled your model with `metrics=['acc']` and you pass your validation generator to `evaluate_generator()`, then `val_acc` and the second element in the list returned by `evaluate_generator()` will be equivalent.